# Force two copies of the same song in different albums on Google Music Manager

Tags: google-play-music

I created my own "greatest hits" "album" for one of my favorite bands by copying songs from their other albums into a new folder. I still have their studio albums in separate folders as well, and I have edited the album tag of the "greatest hits" copies so they are different from the original mp3s. For example:

Folder - Album 1
- Track 1.mp3, with album tag "Album 1"

Folder - Album 2
- Track A.mp3, with album tag "Album 2"

Folder - Greatest Hits
- Track 1.mp3, with album tag "Greatest Hits"
- Track A.mp3, with album tag "Greatest Hits"

The other tags (artist, title, etc) are all uniform; Album is the only one that is different between the studio folders and the greatest hits folder.

Google Music is not uploading both versions of these songs; it is instead only uploading the "Greatest Hits" version of these "duplicate" songs, leaving my studio albums with gaping holes in their tracklistings.

How can I force Google Music to upload both versions o the same song?

Comment: Did you ever get an answer for this? I'm currently talking to support about it, but I haven't gotten anywhere with it yet (will post an answer here if I get a result).

Answer (score 2):

I logged a ticket for this with Google and they said "working as designed". Changing tag info wont work; you need to change fingerprint of file. Use Audiocity to open and save or add a silent millisecond to change the track fingerprint. It will upload after. Google is trying to be too clever here.